# Connect to discord server with the servers webhook url?

Tags: discord, webhooks

I'm trying to figure out how to join a discord server I'm not in using a generated webhook link from the server in which it includes "id" "channel_id" "guild_id" "token"

I know the guild id is the server id, so how do I join it?
The token I'm assuming is used for the webhook that was created.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join a server via those webhooks info. You can only join if you have an invite link. If there is a method is violating Discord TOS so i don't recommend it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).